# How to get last month record from databse in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

> i have a table remaining_bus_fees.

```
id    | date         | student_id | remaining_balance
-----------------------------------------------------
1     | 2019-04-05   | 1          |     500  
2     | 2019-05-10   | 2          |     400     
3     | 2019-05-13   | 3          |     300
```

> Now i need how to get last month record against student_id. here is
>   query i am using. but this is not working for me.

```
$remain_fee = \DB::table('remaining_bus_fees')
        ->whereMonth('date', '<', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->month)
        ->where('student_id', '=', 2)->get();
```

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an error? Or a wrong record?

Comment: Can you use date('m') for test purpose?

Comment: Why you use `<` sign when you need to be equal to that month I guess from what you are asking.

Comment: @Jerodev its working but problem is when record save last month 2019-05-10. then this query show if your date is 2019-06-10. i need query check last month complete record.

Comment: @zeeshan Did you get your problem solved or tried any of the below answers?

Answer (score 0):

At the minute your code is saying where date is "before a month ago" whereas it should be where the date *is* a month ago (i.e. remove `<`). Also, I would suggest adding the year to the query as well otherwise you'll start to get previous years results.

This should get you what you need:

```
$date = Carbon::now()->subMonth();

$remain_fee = \DB::table('remaining_bus_fees')
    ->whereMonth('date', $date->month)
    ->whereYear('date', $date->year)
    ->where('student_id', 2)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is useful queries :

```
 $today=DB::table('remaining_bus_fees')->whereRaw('Date(created_at) = CURDATE()')->where('student_id', 2)->get();

 $yesterday= DB::table('remaining_bus_fees')->whereDate('created_at',Carbon::yesterday())->get();

 $last_7_days= DB::table('remaining_bus_fees')->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->startOfWeek(), Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()])->get();

 $this_month=DB::table('remaining_bus_fees')->whereMonth('created_at',Carbon::now()->month)->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))->where('student_id', 2)->get();

 $last_month=DB::table('remaining_bus_fees')->whereMonth('created_at',Carbon::now()->subMonth()->format('m'))->whereYear('created_at', date('Y'))->where('student_id', 2)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this and it should work fine, you need to convert your Carbon::now() to date format as you will use whereDate here, it will consider only date.

```
$remain_fee = \DB::table('remaining_bus_fees')
        ->whereDate('date', '<', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->toDateString())
        ->where('student_id', '=', 2)->get();
```

Example in tinker

```
>>> App\User::whereDate('created_at', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth()->toDateSt
ring())->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3120
     all: [
       App\User {#3114
         id: 90,
         name: "******",
         email: "******@gmail.com",
         created_at: "2019-05-01 06:17:47",
         updated_at: "2019-05-02 00:28:18",
       },
     ],
   }
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this out,

```
$remain_fee = \DB::table('remaining_bus_fees')
    ->whereMonth('date', '=', Carbon::now()->subMonth()->month)
    ->whereStudentId(2)->get();
```